# How to ignore Properties of an object when deserializing XML with RestSharp

Tags: c#, rest, restsharp, xml-deserialization

Lets say I have an object with only three properties:

```
using RestSharp.Deserializers;
using System;

[DeserializeAs(Name = "item")]
public class MyClass
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DeserializeAs(Name = "id")]
        public int IdFromAPI { get; set; }
    }
```

and an XML like that:

```
<List>
    <timestamp>2018-09-20T10:18:14.070</timestamp>
    <contents>
        <item>
            <id>1</id>
            <name>object1</name>
        </item>
        <item>
            <id>2</id>
            <name>object2</name>
        </item>
    </contents>
    <count>2</count>
</List>
```

I get the data using RestRequest (Method.GET) and deserialize them using

```
RestClient client = new RestClient("SomeURI");
RestRequest request = new RestRequest("someResource", Method.GET);
request.AddHeader(...)
...
List<MyClass> myClassList = client.Execute<List<MyClass>>(request)?.Data;
```

I need from XML to

- map **id** element to property **IdFromAPI** (it works)
- map **name** element to property **Name** (it works)
- property **Id** to be ignored and retain it's default 0 value

Everything works fine but Id and IdFromAPI get the same value (from id element).

**How i can I ignore property Id?**

[NonSerialized] is only valid on field declarations and not on properties.
I cannot find any [XmlIgnore] in RestSharp library and [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore] doesnt work with RestSharp Deserialization. (As a last resort i can use another deserializer)

*Info: I am on .NET Framework 4 and RestSharp 105.2.3 version*

Comment: How about a `[DeserializeAs(Name = "invalid")]` above `Id` ? And maybe make it an `int?`

Comment: This is a good idea (though it's rather a workaround than a solution). I cannot make it int? because the object links to a table in database and this is my primary key, but there is no need to make it nullable as it gets the default value 0 - which is what i want. If there is not an actual tag i could mark this as an answer. Thank you a lot

Comment: "because the object links to a table in database" : that is a choice. I would probably use a DTO just to decouple things, even when the fields were a perfect match. AutoMapper exists for a reason.

Comment: I understand there are many ways to overcome this and some of the solutions you offer are ok. One other way could be using another deserializer. My question though is if RestSharp xml deserializer supports ignoring a property in the deserialization.-